# Use of unassigned local variable error for currency converter? I'm Sorry

Tags: c#

I am very new to coding and I am trying to make a currency converter for my class using C#.

My problem is that my decGrossConvrt is red under my "// Calculations", and the error is "Use of unassigned local variable 'decGrossConvrt'" I'm not sure what to do to fix this, any help would be appreciated.

```
// If Valid
if (blnValid)
{
    if (radUSDFrom.Checked && radEURTo.Checked)
    {
        decConvrtRate = decUSDToEUR;
        decGrossConvrt = decMoneyInput * decConvrtRate;
    }
    else if (radUSDFrom.Checked && radMXNTo.Checked)
    {
        decConvrtRate = decUSDToMXN;
        decGrossConvrt = decMoneyInput * decConvrtRate;
    }
    else if (radEURFrom.Checked && radUSDTo.Checked)
    {
        decConvrtRate = decEURToUSD;
        decGrossConvrt = decMoneyInput * decConvrtRate;
    }
    else if (radEURFrom.Checked && radMXNTo.Checked)
    {
        decConvrtRate = decEURToMXN;
        decGrossConvrt = decMoneyInput * decConvrtRate;
    }
    else if (radMXNFrom.Checked && radUSDTo.Checked)
    {
        decConvrtRate = decMXNToUSD;
        decGrossConvrt = decMoneyInput * decConvrtRate;
    }
    else
    {
        decConvrtRate = decMXNToEUR;
        decGrossConvrt = decMoneyInput * decConvrtRate;
    }
}

// Calculations
decServiceFee = decServiceRate *decGrossConvrt;
decNetConvrt = decGrossConvrt - decServiceFee;



// Display Output
lblGross.Text = decGrossConvrt.ToString("c2");
lblNet.Text = decNetConvrt.ToString("c2");
lblService.Text = decServiceFee.ToString("c2");

// Display Message Box
MessageBox.Show("" + strErr);
```

Comment: Give decGrossConvrt a default value of 0 or something significant in your case. This happens because there is a possibility that your if fails and decGrossConvrt never gets initialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Problem

You are declaring `decGrossConvrt` outside the `if...` block and are assigning it a value inside the `if...` block. As a result, there is a chance that your code will never initialize `decGrossCovert` (i.e. will never assign a value to it.) That's [a problem because](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0165):

> The C# compiler does not allow the use of uninitialized variables.

Here is some code with the same problem. When the `condition` is false, the code never assigns a value to `someNumber`.

```
int someNumber;
bool condition = false;

if (condition)
{
    someNumber = 5;
}

var result = 10 * someNumber; 
// Use of unassigned local variable 'someNumber'
```

## Solution

To resolve it, make sure that all code paths assign a value to `someNumber`.

We can accomplish that like this:

```
int someNumber;
bool condition = false;

if (condition)
{
    someNumber = 5;
}
else 
{
    someNumber = 0; // Assign the default value here

}

var result = 10 * someNumber; // Works
```

Or we can do it like this:

```
int someNumber = 0; // Assign the default value here

bool condition = false;

if (condition)
{
    someNumber = 5;
}

var result = 10 * someNumber; // Works
```